# Missing host problem when using Active Storage in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I don't want that our servers are touched more than needed (we are using CDN for that purpose) I want to use direct links to resources (without active storage redirects)

Direct link can be retreived via

```
object.active_storage_file.service_url
```

But this results with an error:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

In `env/development.rb` I already added :

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = "localhost:3000"
```

However this doesn't solve the problem. Any idea why and how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your controller you can write:

```
before_action do
   ActiveStorage::Current.host = request.base_url
end
```

That would let you give the service url with the host by using say:

```
active_storage_file.blob.service_url if active_storage_file.attached?
```